# Bootstrap not loading fully in webpack project

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I have a webpack project where I've added bootstrap like so in the config file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js',
    bootstrap: 'bootstrap-loader',
  },
  ...
}
```

Bootstrap apparently loads because things are styled correctly and I can interact with the modals and dropdowns. However, bootstrap events are not firing. For example:

```
$('#foo').on('show.bs.dropdown', () => {
    // never gets here when I click on #foo element and dropdown is shown
});
```

I also am getting `false` when I check `typeof($.fn.modal) === 'function'` in the console.

Does anyone know what I need to do to correctly load bootstrap into my webpack project?

Comment: You'd have to load the bundle for the `bootstrap` entry as well. But you cannot load the `app` and the `bootstrap` bundle on the same page. Have a look at https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html .

Comment: @FelixKling I found that loading both in the app entry worked for me. But thanks for the resource, I have a lot to learn about webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out I can load both my `main.js` and `bootstrap-loader` in the `app` entry and now bootstrap loads correctly:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: ['./src/main.js', 'bootstrap-loader']
  },
  ...
}
```